# Sqoop Import from SQL Server, casting binary(10) to bigint

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I have a below column in sql database, however, I need to sqoop import the table and import into hive and get the Max of that table. kindly help with the conversion:

column name __$seqval in the CDC table : 
datatype in sql database showing as : __$seqval(binary(10),NOT NULL)
values of the columns are as below :

```
0x000001D1000003520003 
0x000001D1000003520003 
0x000001D10000035A0003   
0x000001D1000003630003 
0x000001D1000006FB0003 
0x000001D1000007090003    
0x000001D1000007100003 
0x000001D1000007170003 
0x000001D10000071E0003    
0x000001D100000747002C 
0x000001D100000747002C 
0x000001D100000747002E    
0x000001D100000747002E 
0x000001D1000007470030 
0x000001D1000007470030    
0x000001D1000007850002 
0x000001D1000007850002 
0x000001D1000007AA002C    
0x000001D1000007AA002C
```

How do I convert these and get the MAX of them.. in Hive

Comment: How do define "max" in the face of **binary data** without any explanation about what is encoded in there??? Without context it's just nonsense. So you can just answer "42" (quoted freely from *HitchHiker's Guide to the Galactic Cluster*)

Answer (score 0):

When you're pulling it out of SQL-Server, you can use:

```
select convert(bigint, binaryColumnName)
```

...which will pull out the binary values as BigInts. Then when presented to Hadoop it should treat it as BigInt. (I don't know Hadoop so can't tell you how to get a MAX out of it.)